# Nestjs: issue regarding modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have RequestResponseModule which is in lerna package, where I have NasPhHttpService. This service uses HttpService and sends post request, but when i use it in another repository module's service it gives me error that NasPhHttpService is undefined

```
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { DynamicModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { RequestResponseEntity } from './entity/request-response.entity';
import { NasPhHttpService } from './nas-ph-http.service';
import { RequestResponseInterceptor } from './request-response.interceptor';
import { RequestResponseScheduler } from './request-response.scheduler';

export class RequestResponseModule {
  static registerAsync(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: RequestResponseModule,
      imports: [HttpModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([RequestResponseEntity])],
      providers: [NasPhHttpService, RequestResponseInterceptor, RequestResponseScheduler],
      exports: [NasPhHttpService, RequestResponseInterceptor, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([RequestResponseEntity])],
    };
  }
}
```

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { randomUUID as v4 } from 'crypto';
import { catchError, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { METHOD_POST } from './constants';
import { RequestDto } from './dto/request.dto';
import { ResponseDto } from './dto/response.dto';
import { RequestResponseEntity } from './entity/request-response.entity';

@Injectable()
export class NasPhHttpService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(RequestResponseEntity)
    private readonly requestResponseRepository: Repository<RequestResponseEntity>,
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) {}

  private async saveToDatabase(
    response: AxiosResponse<any, any>,
    url: string,
    method: string,
    body: any,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any>
  ) {
    const requestDto: RequestDto = {
      url,
      config,
      body,
      method,
    };

    const responseDto: ResponseDto = {
      status: response.status,
      headers: response.headers,
      body: response.data,
    };

    const requestResponseEntity: RequestResponseEntity = {
      uuid: `REQUEST-RESPONSE-${v4()}`,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      request: requestDto,
      response: responseDto,
      fromProvider: false,
    };

    await this.requestResponseRepository.save(requestResponseEntity);
  }

  public post<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any>): Observable<AxiosResponse<T>> {
    return this.httpService.post(url, data, config).pipe(
      tap(async response => {
        await this.saveToDatabase(response, url, METHOD_POST, data, config);
      }),
      catchError(async error => {
        await this.saveToDatabase(error.response, url, METHOD_POST, data, config);
        return error;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```
import { SomeAuth } from '@common/modules/some/some.auth';
import { ExtPaymentKafkaEventDto } from '@common/modules/consumer/dto';
import { ExtPaymentRepository } from '@common/modules/consumer/ext-payment.repository';
import { HrznAuthPayloadModule } from '@common/modules/hrzn-auth-payload/hrzn-auth-payload.module';
import { RequestResponseModule } from '@hrzn/nestjs-payhub-request-response';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { SomeController } from './some.controller';
import { SomeService } from './some.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ExtPaymentKafkaEventDto]),
    RequestResponseModule.registerAsync(),
    HrznAuthPayloadModule,
  ],
  providers: [SomeService, ExtPaymentRepository, ConfigService, SomeAuth],
  controllers: [SomeController],
  exports: [SomeService],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

I dived into node_modules and found out that in NasPhHttpService's controller HttpService is undefined and it does not have post. during runtime code goes in NasPhHttpService's post method but as this.httpService is undefined it can't send request.